# How to store new session id in a database after session_regenerated_id()

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am trying to use session_regenerate_id() after log-in. but it seemed there was no new session id and its session data in mysql database.

I use custom session handler as below:
https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Session

So I tried to write code instead of session_regenerate_id(). but it still lost sometimes.

```
    $new_session_id = session_create_id();
    $_SESSION['new_session_id'] = $new_session_id;
    
    $_SESSION['destroyed'] = time();
    
    session_commit();

    session_id($new_session_id);
    session_start();
```

Version:
PHP: 7.1
MySQL: 5.6.14

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: checking the results every line, database had the new session  right after session_regenerate_id() at least. Do you have any ideas why new session disappear?

Comment: I found a problem by myself. It was because of same class's new instance I generated in another class. Hope it helps for someone.